# How to put time outs in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to show a success message on firing submit button but only after 10 some sort of time and for that i wrote the following lines.

```
  let timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {  
                           this.success = true;;
                            },500);
```

Simmilarly,i want to close the message after certain amout of time ,let 5 sec .Can anyone suggest me how to do that.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Observable.timer(500).subscribe(() => this.success = true)
```

Comment: Meir,thanks but how can i hide the success msg then?

Comment: Do you hide it by setting success to false?

Answer (score 1):

```
Observable.timer(500).subscribe(() => {
  this.success = true;
  Observable.timer(5000).subscribe(() => this.success = false);
});
```